# Undefined index: expires_in /vendor/google/apiclient/src/client.php in 574 using google api

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using google api and facing below error-

Undefined index: expires_in /vendor/google/apiclient/src/client.php in 574.

I am not sure what this error means when I checked the file it was wriiten-

```
 if (!isset($this->token['expires_in'])) {
            // if the token does not have an "expires_in", then it's considered expired
            return true;
        }

        // If the token is set to expire in the next 30 seconds.
        return ($created + ($this->token['expires_in'] - 30)) < time();
```

Can you please let me know what this error means and how I can resolve it.

This is my custom code -

```
if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
        print 'Enter verification code: ';
        $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);

        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }

        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($accessToken));
    }

    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]  I need to see your code not that code from the client libary.

Comment: are you going to be using this on a server someplace that doesn't  have the ability to open a web browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im curious as to why you are bothering with expire_in?  why not just check $client->isAccessTokenExpired()?  The client library will tell you if its expired or not.  It takes into account clock skew as well.

Example:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
  ...
```

If you really want to check it try `!isset($this->token['expires_in']]` because it sounds like it hasn't been set yet.  doing a `print_r($this->token)` on token might shed some light on your issue.

## update

Wild guess try this, you may be having issues with the parsing of your file.

```
if (file_exists(TOKENPATH)) {
   $userCredentials = json_decode(file_get_contents(TOKENPATH), true);
   $client->setAccessToken($userCredentials['refresh_token']);
   $client->refreshToken($userCredentials['refresh_token']);
   $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($userCredentials['refresh_token']);
    }
```

Comment: @DalmTo, I am doing in this way only (this is my code in my local file)
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
but the error I mentioned it is coming from default google library file.

Comment: Please add your code to your question.  Code from the library isnt going to help debug your issue.

Comment: I have edited my question and added my custom code, can you help me with this, It would be a great help.

Comment: try my update, this really just a guess I dont have time to test your code right now.  Although your code is similar to my standard samples